# Enumerate CSS style elements using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css

First up, JavaScript is definitely not my native tongue. Nevertheless, I've been tasked with creating a web page where the user can use a colour picker to change CSS elements. These then need to be sent back to the server to be stored in a database. It's all working so far except the last part, because I'm stuck reading the required elements.

Using the code below works fine for any single word elements, such as `color`, but fails for any hyphenated ones, such as `background-color`, which return `undefined`. I've tested this against a number of other elements for consistency.

Any ideas as to why this fails, preferably with suggestions for fixing it? Alternatively, do you have a code snippet that does work for this purpose?

```
function Save(form) {
var cssRules;
var Q = "";

for (var S = 0; S < document.styleSheets.length; S++){
    if (document.styleSheets[S]['rules']) {
        cssRules = 'rules';
    } else if (document.styleSheets[S]['cssRules']) {
        cssRules = 'cssRules';
    }

    for (var R = 0; R < document.styleSheets[S][cssRules].length; R++) {
        if (document.styleSheets[S][cssRules][R].selectorText == '.event') {
            Q += "+bc=" + document.styleSheets[S][cssRules][R].style['color'] + "+bb=" + document.styleSheets[S][cssRules][R].style['background-color'];
        }
        // Similar code for other elements goes here
    }
}

form.css.value = Q;
form.submit();
}
```

Example section of the CSS style sheet:

```
.event {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 10px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: line-through;
    color: red;
    background-color: #ffff99;
    height:20px;
    width:20px;
}
```

This is the kind of HTML element I need the style sheet values for:

```
<td class="event">11</td>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because in Javascript as in other languages the hyphen is not a valid symbol character. When you use strings as indexes, like

```
style["background-color"]
```

is the same as doing

```
style.background-color
```

which is not valid, to access hyphened css properties you need to remove the hyphen and uppercase the next character, like

```
style.backgroundColor; // or style["backgroundColor"];
```

Comment: While this is essentially the same as Jason's answer I'll accept yours because of the additional detail, which is a help to me. Thanks.

Comment: Slightly misleading: the hyphen is an invalid character in an **identifier**. It's not invalid in a property name, as you can see by doing something like `var o = { "%1-2*-3": "test" }; alert(o["%1-2*-3"]);`. However, you are probably correct that the reason CSS property names are different in JavaScript is so that they can be used as identifiers and hence the dot notation can be used to access style properties.

Comment: style["background-color"] IS NOT the same as style.background-color

Comment: @VincentMcNabb, why is style["background-color"] NOT the same as style.background-color?

Comment: @series0ne because style.background-color would be the same as writing style['background'] - color

Answer (score 4):

To set CSS properties in JavaScript you need to use camelCase for hyphened properties. For example:

```
/* CSS */
background-color: red;

/* JS */
element.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
```

Answer (score 4):

To add to @Francisco's answer, in JavaScript an object property can contain any string. However, if it contains characters that are illegal for naming variables, then it cannot be accessed with the `.` operator, and must be accessed with `[]`. An extreme [example](http://jsfiddle.net/MumZc/) of using such characters would be:

```
var o = { "◀▶": "hello!" };
o["◀▶"]; // hello!
```

However, we cannot write `o.◀▶`, as that will raise a `SyntaxError` since *these* unicode characters are not valid identifiers names. However, note that unicode characters can be used in identifier names and are valid as per ECMAScript 5th ed. but only for certain classes of Unicode categories. So one could [write](http://jsfiddle.net/QKAut/):

```
var o = {};
o.Π = "hello world";
o.Π; // "hello world"
```

See section [7.6 Identifier Names and Identifiers](http://www.ecmascript.org/docs.php) in the documentation for 3rd ed. or 5th ed. for more information regarding valid identifier names.

The style property of DOM elements is an object of `CSSStyleDeclaration` and can be manipulated in a couple of ways. Being a host object, some browsers could provide more functionality than others. On Webkit browsers (Chrome and Safari), you could use the `[]` notation to set style properties using their CSS2 names.

```
document.body.style['background-color'] = "#CCC";
```

The interface for [`CSSStyleDeclaration`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Style/css.html#CSS-CSSStyleDeclaration) contains a `setProperty` method that can also be used for setting these properties:

```
interface CSSStyleDeclaration {
    ...
    void setProperty(in DOMString propertyName, 
                     in DOMString value, 
                     in DOMString priority)
            raises(DOMException);
    ...
}
```

Using `setProperty`, we could write:

```
document.body.style.setProperty("background-color", "orange", null);
```

We can use `getPropertyValue` to get the current value using it's CSS2 name:

```
document.body.style.getPropertyValue("background-color");
```

Finally, as other answers have mentioned, you can always use the [`CSS2Properties`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Style/css.html#CSS-CSS2Properties) interface for conveniently accessing the CSS properties for a style object. They are equivalent to calling `setProperty` and `getPropertyValue` on the style object with the corresponding property name. From the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Style/css.html#CSS-CSS2Properties) (contains names for all properties that should be exposed by this interface):

> The CSS2Properties interface represents a convenience mechanism for retrieving and setting properties within a CSSStyleDeclaration. The attributes of this interface correspond to all the properties specified in CSS2. Getting an attribute of this interface is equivalent to calling the getPropertyValue method of the CSSStyleDeclaration interface. Setting an attribute of this interface is equivalent to calling the setProperty method of the CSSStyleDeclaration interface.

In any browser that supports this interface (it's not required), we can query/update the style object such as:

```
document.body.style.backgroundColor = "black";
```

or

```
document.body.style["backgroundColor"] = "black";
```

See [examples](http://jsfiddle.net/Pg4LG/2/) for all of the above.

Comment: Indeed, thank you for your answer. Maybe I should just stick to C and Perl. At least those make sense to me. :)

Comment: @Francisco - you're welcome, I discovered about unicode characters in identifier names myself, so it was a good learning experience :) @John - Thankfully those languages don't suffer from level 1..n specs that come out every other week :)